# How to mock two consecutive web requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, moq

I am trying to test a method that makes two consecutive web requests.

Up until now I only tested single requests using [this solution using an object called TestWebRequest](http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/how-to-mock-httpwebrequest-when-unit-testing/) and that works like a charm for single requests. If you're not familiar with it, [TestWebRequest](http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/how-to-mock-httpwebrequest-when-unit-testing/) intercepts the Web Request mechanism and works behind the scene to return an expected response. That makes it possible to test the actual service without using a mock.

But now the logic of one of my methods has changed to something like this (in pseudocode)

```
public void MakePayment(PaymentRequest request)
{
    var statusRequest = webService.GetPaymentStatus(new PaymentStatusRequest()
            {
                OrderId = request.OrderId
            });

    if (statusRequest.StatusId != 100)
    {
     var responseXml = webService.GetResponse(GetRequestXml(request));
     /*.. process response ..*/
    }
}
```

Is there a way to extend [TestWebRequest](http://blog.salamandersoft.co.uk/index.php/2009/10/how-to-mock-httpwebrequest-when-unit-testing/) to handle two requests or is there an alternative that I could use to test this method?

Here is an example of a working test:

```
 [Test]
 public void MakePayment()
 {
      var response = @"<XML>..</XML>";
      TestWebRequest request = TestWebRequestCreate.CreateTestRequest(response);
      var result = webService.MakePayment(1, new PaymentRequest());
      var expectedResponse = new PaymentResponse()
      {
          Status = 23
      };
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedResponse, result);  
 }
```

Now if MakePayment suddenly makes two requests, then we need a way to mock two fake responses like this:

```
 [Test]
 public void MakePayment()
 {
      var response1 = @"<XML>..</XML>";
      var response2 =  @"<XML>..</XML>";
      TestWebRequest request1 = TestWebRequestCreate.CreateTestRequest(response1);
      TestWebRequest request2= TestWebRequestCreate.CreateTestRequest(response2);
      var result = webService.MakePayment(1, new PaymentRequest());
      var expectedResponse = new PaymentResponse()
      {
          Status = 23
      };
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedResponse, result);  
 }
```

Which doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the actual code you're trying to test rather than pseudocode? I have an answer for you but there are too many assumptions I'm having to make because I'm second guessing what you're actually testing

Comment: I just posted the actual code. I just make two web requests within the same method. If I make one, then the test passes, but if I make two, then the TestWebRequest returns the same response. I can't make it return two different responses in a particular order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by updating TestWebReqestCreate factory method to accept two requests.

Here is the updated code. It's not very elegant but works well for two requests and you don't have to change all your existing tests for single requests.

I guess it can be updated to chain any number of requests but I didn't need to do that for now so I came up with something quick.

I hope that helps someone who was stuck like me

```
internal class TestWebRequestCreate : IWebRequestCreate
    {
        static WebRequest nextRequest;
        static WebRequest nextRequest2;
        private static bool used = false;
        static object lockObject = new object();

        static public WebRequest NextRequest
        {
            get { return nextRequest; }
            set
            {
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    nextRequest = value;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>See <see cref="IWebRequestCreate.Create"/>.</summary>
        public WebRequest Create(Uri uri)
        {
            if (used)
            {
                return nextRequest2;
            }
            else
            {
                used = true;
                return nextRequest;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Utility method for creating a TestWebRequest and setting
        /// it to be the next WebRequest to use. It can now accept a subsequent request</summary>
        /// <param name="response1">The response the TestWebRequest will return.</param>
        /// <param name="response2">The subsequent response the TestWebRequest will return.</param>
        public static TestWebRequest CreateTestRequest(string response1, string response2 = null)
        {
            TestWebRequest request1 = new TestWebRequest(response1);
            used = false;
            nextRequest = request1;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response2))
            {
                TestWebRequest request2 = new TestWebRequest(response2);
                nextRequest2 = request2;
            }

            return request1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested the example you give as a working test? That will not pass because `expectedResponse` is instantiated within your test code and cannot be the same object as the one returned from the `webService.MakePayment` call. The article you linked to is testing that 2 strings are equal, not 2 complex types. You also don't actually use the `TestWebRequest` object that you instantiate in your test.

That said, you can accomplish what you're trying to test, by either being in control of the 2 requests that are created and passed in to the 2 calls to `webRequest.MakePayment` or by using Moq's callback feature, something like this (untested code):

```
webRequestMock.Setup(x => x.MakePayment(1, It.IsAny<PaymentRequest>()).Returns(It.IsAny<PaymentResponse>()).CallBack((PaymentRequest request, PaymentResponse response) => VerifyResponse(request, response));

private void VerifyResponse(PaymentRequest request, PaymentResponse response) 
{
    // do some checks to determine whether it's the first call or the second, based on something uniquely different between to 2 requests - I need more actual code from you before I can tidy this up
    // e.g. (pseudocode)
    if (request.SomeValue == firstRequestValue) 
    {
        response.ShouldEqual(firstReponse);
    }
    else 
    {
        response.ShouldEqual(secondReponse);
    }

}
```

I say that this is untested code because I'm not sure whether the response that is returned can be captured and passed into the callback (because it is the return value) or not.

Comment: The webRequest is not a mock, it's the actual service and that's because I am testing it. TestWebRequest is used internally withinn the webRequest service so when it tries to post an XML, TestWebRequest will return the expected responseXML.
This is a really smart way of testing web services but I can't extend it to handle multiple requests